# PHP and jQuery: show/hide div if user logged in or not

Tags: php, jquery

EDIT:
thanks a lot for all your comments/replies. 
Even if i remove the JS, and use the PHP if/else statements only, i still get the same error.

i keep on running into the same error:

The 2 divs below are visible whereas only one of them should be shown at a time (whether or not the user is logged in).

For simplicity purposes, i removed the html inside the 2 divs.

```
<div id="header_wrapper">

<div id="loginbutton"></div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>    
</ul>
</div>

<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['id'])){  ?>

<script>
document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("loginbutton").style.display = "show";
</script>
<?php }
else {  ?>
<script>
document.getElementById("loginbutton").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "show";
</script>

<?php 
}
?>
</div>
```

The $_SESSION['id'] is not empty. Indeed if i echo $_SESSION['id'] on the page, i get the correct session #.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use `else`, use `if (isset($_SESSION['id']))` and btw, it should be `...dislpay = "visible";`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will matter but try changing `<script>` to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: thanks for your help, it's still buggy, going to check the js console

Comment: Once you are logged in, there's no way to log out?

Comment: Change `<?` to `<?php` what happens?

Comment: Why not use PHP to echo either one of those instead of echoing the javascript? What if JS is disabled by the user?

Comment: @Salketer Even with PHP only i get the exact same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this if you put your html inside `php` if blocks , or it is necessary to use javascript you can do it also by using only `php` then why adding JS

```
<div id="header_wrapper">
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['id'])){  ?>
<div id="loginbutton"></div>
<?php }
else {  ?>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>    
</ul>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: PHP is what I tried at first, but no luck, it still shows the 2 divs at the same time.

Comment: How in `if/else` only one condition will run how both conditions run at same time think man ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, i don't understand either ! i ve never had such a problem before !

Comment: This is the correct answer, but you have to use another iftest. When the user logs in, set $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true. Then you can check if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['LoggedIn']) { around the <div>

Answer (score 3):

If you use session like following exaple you can hide the div

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) { ?><div>div content</div><?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

```
<div id="loginbutton"></div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>    
</ul>
</div>

<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id'])){  ?>
<script>
document.getElementById("loginbutton").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "show";
</script>
<?php }
else {  ?>

<script>
document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("loginbutton").style.display = "show";
</script>

<?php 
}
?>
</div>
```

this should work

Comment: can you tell me what exactly is happening? like when a user is logged in what is being shown?

Comment: EDIT: When the user is logged in, both the divs are visible. As soon as the user logs out, only #menu is visible whereas it should be #loginbutton

Comment: try making it 'and' instead of 'or' in the if statement

Comment: try my updated code and are u deleting the sessions after the user logs out?

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
.style.display = "show";
```

**TO**

```
.style.display = "block";
```

*OR*

```
.style.display = "";
```

AND **change**

```
<script>
```

**TO**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

There is no valid value called show in this context. If you have Firebug (or similar) check in the console for further js-errors. If you don't, download it right away :-)

Comment: `<script>` alone is valid under HTML5

Comment: @random - yes, but there's nothing indicating it's a html5-document.

Comment: thanks for your help, it's still buggy, going to check the js console

Comment: @CharlieHarris - you're welcome. What message/warning/errors do you get?